# Zend Framework 2 - separate logic on action method

Tags: zend-framework2

How I ought to separate logic on action method in controller, for example in controller action I have code for parsing xml and save file. I ought to move code for xml to "module" other class and add to getServiceConfig ?
Any some suggestion ?

```
//in module.php
public function getServiceConfig()
{        
    return array(
      'Xlsx' => function($sm) {            
                $model = new \Application\Model\Xlsx();
                $model->setServiceLocator($sm);
                return $model;
       },
    );
}

//in constroller
$xlsx = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Xlsx');
$dataArray = $xlsx->import($fileTab);
```

Comment: What is the problem actually? Idea is fine, just do it. ;) You have access to ServiceLocator in controller so I can't see the problem. Maybe show us what have you tried, then we will be able to help you.

Comment: I created folder for class/module where each i can use in controller, but i don't know if it's ok ?, yes I used ServiceLocator for this
It's idea is seperate logic from method in controller to model if not applicable db entities ?

Comment: There are whole bunch of open source modules. Just check how they do it.

Comment: Idea is fine, code looks fine. What is the problem? The only thing I would change is not to pass `$sm` to model,  but only chosen services - probably `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`. This is how it's suggested in official user Guide and it makes sense.

Comment: some like this ? [example]http://codepad.viper-7.com/3SDDuH